# HierarchyRequestError: DOM Exception 3 when trying to insertbefore

Tags: jquery, domexception

While trying to insert option with insertbefore, I am getting this error.
Uncaught Error: HierarchyRequestError: DOM Exception 3

```
var target = $('#divA option:selected').prev().first();
    var options = $('#divA option:selected');
    if (options.prev().text() == target.text()) {
        return;
    }
    options.insertBefore(target);
```

if `options.length > 2`  this error occurs, if it is 1 or 2 there is no problem. 
when multiple selection goes to top, all selected items will be disappeared.
what is the problem? could you help me?

sample :http://jsfiddle.net/tHVsw/

Comment: Can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net? This happens when you try to insert an element before/after itself.

Comment: yes, http://jsfiddle.net/tHVsw/ and also you can see from here,
when multiple selection goes to top, all selected items will be disappeared.

Comment: This can also occur if an operation would create a cycle in the hierarchy (add a parent to it's descendent).

Answer (score 5):

This error is thrown when insertion of an element to a specific point in the DOM is not allowed(*ie. it 
is not possible*), you can use an `if` statement for checking whether insertion is possible or not.

```
if ( !target.prev().length ) 
    target.parent().prepend(options);
else 
    target.before(options);
```

If the `length` of previous sibling of the target element is 0, prepend the element(s) to the parent element, otherwise insert it before the target element.

http://jsfiddle.net/fKx68/